Positiveness of the solution of a system of elliptical equations
Given $u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, by Riesz Representation Theorem we know there exists a unique $v=B(u)\in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ weak solution of
$$
(1) \,\,-\Delta v + v = u, \mathbb{R}^N.
$$
Suppose there is  $u \in H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ weak solution of
$$
(2) \,\,-\Delta u + B(u) = f(u), \mathbb{R}^N,
$$
where $f$ is a real function defined in $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(s) = 0$ if $s\leq 0$. In addition suppose
$$
\|u\|^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u|^2 + B(u)u
$$
defines a norm in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$.
Assuming all these information, is it possible conclude that $u^- = 0$, where $u^-(x) := max \{-u(x), 0\}$ ?
My attempt: Weak formulation of $(2)$ applied to $u^-$ yields
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} |\nabla u \nabla u^-| + B(u)u^- =  \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}f(u) u^- = \int_{\{u\leq 0\}}f(u) u^- = 0.
$$
Using the identity $u = u^+-u^-$ and the linearity of the B we obtain
$$-\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}[ |\nabla u^-|^2 + B(u^-)u^-] + \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}B(u^+)u^- = 0.$$To conclude, I think I have to show that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}B(u^+)u^-  = 0,
$$
but I don't know how to do it.
